# Mobile phone CSS

Tags: css

I'd like to make a css for mobile as my site looks really deformed on mobile, but i have no idea how to do a separate mobile version from the desktop verion. I've seen that phones have an option to change between the two so i was just wondering how it's done and how i could do it and if you guys have any tips regarind making a css for mobile, like the dos and don'ts that'd be great.

Also would i need to make one for different models etc or do i make 1 that will be for mobile devices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries like in this example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

More infos [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: You are welcome, please mark my answer by clicking on green check image below downvote button

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate stylesheet "responsive.css" and add your styles between this media query:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    /*Your style goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers suggesting using `@media` queries, you may need to add the following meta tag to your `<head>` tag in order for the browser to recognise that the device has a smaller aspect ratio:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

Example HTML/CSS using `@media` queries and the viewport `meta` tag:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      .box {
        background: blue;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```